# Mysql: order by two column, use filesort

Tags: mysql, filesort, mysql-slow-query-log

I have trouble ordering two columns.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM articles WHERE option <>0 AND deleted=0 ORDER BY
    date_added DESC, category_id DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 500
```

> id    select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows
>     Extra 1     SIMPLE  articles    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    437168  Using
>   where; Using filesort

I add single indexes for (option, deleted, date_added, category_id)

When i used:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM articles WHERE option <>0 AND deleted=0 ORDER BY
    date_added DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 500
```

or

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM articles WHERE option <>0 AND deleted=0 ORDER BY
    category_id DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 500
```

Using only where

I tried add index to (option, deleted, date_added, category_id) but it works only when i try sort by one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be very hard to get MySQL to use an index for this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE option <> 0 AND deleted = 0
ORDER BY date_added DESC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 500
```

You can try a composite index: `articles(deleted, date_added, option)`.  By covering the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`, MySQL *might* use it.

If you can add an `optionflag` column for equality testing (rather than `<>`), then write the query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE optionflag = 1 AND deleted = 0
ORDER BY date_added DESC
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 500;
```

Then an index on `articles(deleted, optionflag, date_added desc)` would work well.

Otherwise a subquery might work for you:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM articles
      WHERE deleted = 0
      ORDER BY date_added DESC
     ) a
WHERE option <> 0
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 500;
```

This materializes the intermediate result, but it is doing an `order by` anyway.  And, the final ordering is not guaranteed to be surfaced in the outer query, but it does work in practice (and is close to guaranteed because of the materialization).